# Missing begin document error in basic file

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex

There's an error that's driving me nuts and latex doesn't help me understand what's going on.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Then you can try:

```
$ pdflatex error.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./error.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlttr2.cls
Document Class: scrlttr2 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (letter)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize12pt.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/DIN.lco)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/invoice/invoice.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/fp/fp.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/invoice/invoice.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[
                              1995/12/01]
?
```

Does someone here understand what's going on?

Comment: There have been changes to `graphicx`. Just call `\usepackage{graphicx}` first before `invoice`. Are you sure you need the `pdftex` option? I don't think so!

Comment: Try to put *something* inside `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have a very old TeX installation and only two languages installed for proper hyphenation. Installing a fresh TeX Live 2016 will most likely resolve your issue.

Comment: Sidenote: option `pdftex` is unneded and often disturbing something.

Comment: @Johannes_B er, no....

Comment: @Matsmath as shown by the error latex never gets as far as `\begin{document}` so adding something after it won't help much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `invoice` package completely breaks latex in its current form.

If you take a copy and change line 152 from

```
\input{fp}
```

to

```
\RequirePackage{fp}
```

then your test file works.

As it is it loads `fp.tex` which  defines *stub* versions of latex commands for use with plain TeX, but it breaks latex completely.

Comment: I have emailed the package maintainer with the bug report

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I manually changed `invoice.sty` as  suggested and it worked.